# Excel formula for greater than but less than with several tiers

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a few hundred rows of data, and each has a number between 1 and 200, and I'd like to put them in categories of 1-5 depending on where that number is.

The categories look like this:

---

```
Zones   Min  Max
1       0    35
2       35   60
3       60   85
4       85   110
5       110  200
```

---

I want to assign it a Zone if it is greater than the Min, but less than the Max.

I have 2 formulas I've been working with to solve it. One is a nested IF AND statement:

```
=IF(A1<=35,1,IF(AND(A1<=60,A1>35),2,IF(AND(A1<=85,A1>60),3,IF(AND(A1<=110,A1>85),4,IF(AND(A1<=200,A1>110),2,"TOO BIG")))))
```

The 2nd formula attempts to use a SUMPRODUCT function:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$6,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1<=$E$2:$E$6),-- (A1>$D2:$D$6),ROW($2:$6)))
```

Rather than have to continue to adjust the numeric values manually, I set them as absolutes, which is why this formula is slightly different. The E column is the Max value set, and the D is the Min value set.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? How to return a zone number, based on an input, such as `20`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Scott Craner actually gave me something that works perfectly. But I wanted it to assign Zone 1 whenever something fell between 0 and 35, Zone 2 between 35 and 60, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=MATCH(A1,{0,35,60,85,110})
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to have the numbers in the array match a particular set of cells? Or do they have to be numbers? This works fine, just wondering if I can take it to the next step of simplicity for my team.

Comment: @jso - Say you put `0`,`35`,`60`,`85`, `110` in cells `B1`, `B2`, etc.  The formula you'd use then is `=MATCH(A1,B1:B5)`.

Comment: Yes, if your min numbers are in G1:G5 then: `=MATCH(A1,G1:G5)` they do need to sorted.

Comment: @BruceWayne This is a standard Match function.  No need for CSE.

Comment: Very cool way.  Never had a list inside the standalone `MATCH` function.

Comment: @ian0411 you can do the same with VLOOKUP: `=VLOOKUP(A1,{0,1;35,2;60,3;85,4;110,5},2,TRUE)`

Comment: @ScottCraner, that is awesome.  I have to really follow you guys to learn all these cool tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `VLOOKUP` and you just need to set the min number:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$6,2,1)
```

[image]

The key is the 4th parameter needs to set to `1` which means `TRUE`.  It will find the closest value and return the zone for you.

But noticed that you have overlaps like 35 or 60 etc. that you will need to adjust your value column.